# Rounded images for WPF application using xamarin.forms

Tags: wpf, xamarin.forms

I want rounded images for my WPF application and I'm developing my WPF Application using xamarin.forms not through native code.I am goggling this for the last 2 hours and couldn't find any solution. I've found some solutions that works for android using renders or the solution that works for native wpf code.

And,found a [Plugin for circle images](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle) but I'm unable to initialize this plugin in my WPF application.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: I didnt think Xamarin Forms could target WPF?

Comment: @DeanChalk it does [support it since XF3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF/) but the package [doesn't support it yet](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ImageCirclePlugin/issues/66)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a plugin or a custom renderer to do that. It's simpler than you might think. Here is how to do it:

```
<Frame HasShadow="False" WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="70" CornerRadius="35">
  <Image Source="yourImageNameGoesHere" />
</Frame>
```